# Bash comparing variables string escape character showing

Tags: bash, jenkins-pipeline

I have an issue with comparing variables string in the shell of the pipeline. It is using escape character to separate each letter of the string

script :

```
stage('switch') {


    node("nodename") {
  
     sh """

    getprimary=`sudo cat /pathfile/getprimary.txt`
    standbyresponse=`sudo cat /pathfile/getprimary.txt`
    echo "\${getprimary}"
    echo "\${standbyresponse}"
    if [[ "\${getprimary}" == "\${standbyresponse}" ]]; then  
    echo "The server is equal"  
    elif [[  "\${getprimary}" != "\${standbyresponse}"  ]]; then  
    echo "The hostname not equal to primary"
fi

"""

}

}
```

Output

```
primary.co.uk
standby-first-one.co.uk

if [[ primary.co.uk == \s\t\a\n\d\b\y\-\f\i\r\s\t\-\o\n\e\.c\o\.u\k\ ]]
```

I want to know why is the primary.co.uk does not have backslash separating the variables but the other variables has.

Comment: What are these backslashes supposed to do? And why do you sometimes `${varname}` and sometimes `{$varname}`? Anyway, what you have is not syntactically correct and it cannot produce the output you show. Please edit your question, fix everything that needs to be, and show the real output.

Comment: That is the real output. I changed the domain name in and have corrected it.

Comment: No, it's not. `echo "\${getprimary}"` prints exactly `${getprimary}`, nothing like `primary.co.uk`. And there is nothing in your script that would print `if [[ primary.co.uk == ...` You could maybe read [this post about How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: okay. The script is groovy and the file contain domain name which have changed. Basically, the domain name   is assigned to the   variable and is output it using echo. I am not sure what else to explain again here. It is groovy in jenkins., anyway not sure what else to add

Comment: You should probably test your script before embedding it in your jenkins configuration file. And if you use `bash` specific features (like `[[ ... ]]`) you should definitely use `bash`, not `sh`. And I still don't understand how you can have the output you show. Does jenkins echo the commands it executes? If yes, why do we see only the echo of the `if [[ ... ]]` statement? If not why do we see it?

Comment: Issue resolved  and just a space at the end of the host name. regarding the output, it seems is standard way in jenkins to put the escape character when comparing strings

Answer (score 0):

This is resolved now as there is space atthe end of the host name and I used | sed 's/ //g'

```
 stage('switch') {


    node("nodename") {
  
     sh """

    getprimary=`sudo cat /pathfile/getprimary.txt | sed 's/ //g' `
    standbyresponse=`sudo cat /pathfile/getprimary.txt | sed 's/ //g' `
    echo "\${getprimary}"
    echo "\${standbyresponse}"
    if [[ "\${getprimary}" == "\${standbyresponse}" ]]; then  
    echo "The server is equal"  
    elif [[  "\${getprimary}" != "\${standbyresponse}"  ]]; then  
    echo "The hostname not equal to primary"
fi

"""

}

}
```